# LINQ query losing select when joining two queries

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join

Just to set the context a little, I'm trying to use queries with mysql that use Late row lookup as shown in this article

https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

but that's a story for another day but the idea is that you do a key search on the table and then join it onto the whole table to force a late row lookup and the problem is coming from my LINQ queries when joined together.

-- Key search query --

*Calling Code*

```
IQueryable<int> keySearch = _defaultQueryFactory.Load(ContextEnums.ClientContext, MapEntityToDTO(), whereStatement, clientID).OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(startRow).Take(pageSize).Select(x => x.ID);
```

*Resulting Query*

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`Sys_InvoiceID`
FROM `tblinvoice` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE 3 = `Extent1`.`FK_StatusID`
 ORDER BY 
`Extent1`.`InvoiceDate` ASC LIMIT 0,430
```

-- Full Table Search --

*Calling Code*

```
IQueryable<InvoiceDTOModel> tableSearch = _defaultQueryFactory.Load(ContextEnums.ClientContext, MapEntityToDTO(), null, clientID, true).OrderBy(orderBy);
```

*Resulting Query*

```
   SELECT
    `Extent1`.`ID`, 
    `Extent1`.`C1`, 
    `Extent1`.`C2`, 
    `Extent1`.`C3`, 
    `Extent1`.`C4`, 
    `Extent1`.`C5`, 
    `Extent1`.`C6`, 
    `Extent2`.`SID`, 
    `Extent2`.`S1, 
    `Extent2`.`S2`, 
    `Extent2`.`S3`, 
    `Extent3`.`EID`, 
    `Extent3`.`E1`, 
    `Extent4`.`DID`, 
    `Extent4`.`D1`, 
    `Extent4`.`D2`, 
    `Extent4`.`D3`, 
    `Extent4`.`D4`, 
    `Extent4`.`D5`    
    FROM `tbl1` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `tbl2` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`SID` = `Extent2`.`SID` INNER JOIN `tbl3` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent1`.`EID` = `Extent3`.`EID` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl4` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent4`.`DID`
     ORDER BY 
    `Extent1`.`C4` ASC
```

-- Joining the Two Together --

*Calling Code*

```
keySearch.Join(tableSearch, key => key, table => table.ID, (key, table) => table).OrderBy(orderBy).ToListAsync();
```

*Resulting Query*

```
 SELECT
    `Join3`.`ID`, 
    `Join3`.`C1`, 
    `Join3`.`C1`, 
    `Join3`.`C1`, 
    `Join3`.`C1`, 
    `Join3`.`C1`, 
    `Join3`.`C1`, 
    `Join3`.`SID`, 
    `Join3`.`S1, 
    `Join3`.`S2`, 
    `Join3`.`S3`, 
    `Join3`.`EID`, 
    `Join3`.`E1`, 
    `Join3`.`DID`, 
    `Join3`.`D1`, 
    `Join3`.`D2`, 
    `Join3`.`D3`, 
    `Join3`.`D4`, 
    `Join3`.`D5`   
    FROM ( 
        `Extent1`.`ID`, 
        `Extent1`.`C1`, 
        `Extent1`.`C2`, 
        `Extent1`.`C3`, 
        `Extent1`.`C4`, 
        `Extent1`.`C5`, 
        `Extent1`.`C6` 
    FROM `tblinvoice` AS `Extent1`
     WHERE 3 = `Extent1`.`EID`
     ORDER BY 
    `Extent1`.`C4` ASC LIMIT 0,430) AS `Limit1` INNER JOIN (SELECT
    `Extent1`.`ID`, 
    `Extent1`.`C1`, 
    `Extent1`.`C2`, 
    `Extent1`.`C3`, 
    `Extent1`.`C4`, 
    `Extent1`.`C5`, 
    `Extent1`.`C6`, 
    `Extent2`.`SID`, 
    `Extent2`.`S1, 
    `Extent2`.`S2`, 
    `Extent2`.`S3`, 
    `Extent3`.`EID`, 
    `Extent3`.`E1`, 
    `Extent4`.`DID`, 
    `Extent4`.`D1`, 
    `Extent4`.`D2`, 
    `Extent4`.`D3`, 
    `Extent4`.`D4`, 
    `Extent4`.`D5`    
    FROM `tbl1` AS `Extent2` INNER JOIN `tbl2` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent2`.`SID` = `Extent3`.`SID` INNER JOIN `tblstatus` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent2`.`EID` = `Extent4`.`EID` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl3` AS `Extent5` ON `Extent2`.`ID` = `Extent5`.`DID`) AS `Join3` ON `Limit1`.`ID` = `Join3`.`ID`
     ORDER BY 
    `Join3`.`C4` ASC
```

Basically the inner select brings back

```
FROM ( 
            `Extent1`.`ID`, 
            `Extent1`.`C1`, 
            `Extent1`.`C2`, 
            `Extent1`.`C3`, 
            `Extent1`.`C4`, 
            `Extent1`.`C5`, 
            `Extent1`.`C6` 
        FROM `tblinvoice` AS `Extent1`
         WHERE 3 = `Extent1`.`EID`
         ORDER BY 
        `Extent1`.`C4` ASC LIMIT 0,430) AS `Limit1`
```

Instead of

```
FROM (                
           `Extent1`.`ID`,                
            FROM `tblinvoice` AS `Extent1`
             WHERE 3 = `Extent1`.`EID`
             ORDER BY 
            `Extent1`.`C4` ASC LIMIT 0,430) AS `Limit1`
```

--Note--

The actual query selects around 15 columns, I've just shortened it to this example, it has an effect on the search as the dataset grows in size and it shouldn't be selecting all of the fields but i suspect there's an error in my join.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be MySQL provider defect (does not happen with SqlServer) which cannot be avoided, thus killing the whole idea for separate filter and join.

Comment: Bit of a shame really, thanks for the response though @IvanStoev